# Is there a way to add the comment section to the node edit page?

Tags: 7, comments

I am developing a site which will be used for information gathering.  All views are designed to send users to node edit pages (instead of node view pages) so that they can see and update information at the same time.  I would like to use the comment system, but I have not been able to figure out (yet) how to enable the comment section on a node edit page.  This section show up on the node view. I would like to know if there is a way to make it show up on the node edit page as well.

Comment: ever tried `page--node--edit.tpl.php` ?

Comment: Nope, could you and and example please?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this for setting up a custom edit template if you don't want it site wide: http://www.nybergtechnology.com/blog/2013/11/11/how-create-edit-tpl-node-type-drupal-7

then you should be able to add:

```
<?php print render($content['links']); ?>  // only if you want the links to show

<?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
```

to the bottom, to produce the comments. (I didn't test this, so it may be gibberish)